# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (1, 28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, ocr

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import numpy as np
import h5py

import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model, Sequential

word_dict = {0:'0',1:'1',2:'2',3:'3',4:'4',5:'5',6:'6',7:'7',8:'8',9:'9',10:'A',11:'B',12:'a',13:'b'}

model = load_model('small_letter_model.h5')

# Prediction on external image...

img = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/Swaraj/Desktop/img_3.jpg')
img_copy = img.copy()

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))

img_copy = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_copy, (21,21), 0)
#detector.avg = img_copy.astype(float)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

img_final = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
#img_final =np.reshape(img, (0,0,0,0))

#img_final = np.array(img)
img_final = img_final.reshape(1,28,28,1)

img_pred = word_dict[np.argmax(model.predict(img_final))]

cv2.putText(img, "", (20,25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.7, color = (0,0,230))
cv2.putText(img, "Prediction: " + img_pred, (20,410), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.3, color =  (255,0,30))
cv2.imshow('Handwritten Math Symbol Recognition _ _ _ ', img)


while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i got error as "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (1, 28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)" while recognition of image,
while creation of model give input shape is input_shape=(128,128,3) code is base_model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2( include_top=False, input_shape=(128,128,3), pooling='max', weights='imagenet')
How does the generator receive a (1,28,28) array? Any help is appreciated! please give suggestion
thank you in advance